# How to make this angular shaped border (as its shown in the image)?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make div borders with this kind of angular area. Exactly as it says in the image, I have marked with red oval.

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <header><b>List header</b></header>
       <ul>
          <li>List 1</li>
          <li>List 2</li>
          <li>List 3</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    border:2px solid gray;
    background: #DC143C;
    padding:10px;

}
.box ul{
   list-style-type:square;  
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fry2ppqu/)

Comment: there is no border like this one. you need to shape a new element this way and put it near the left border to achieve this visual result.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow).  The shape you want to achieve would need a similar approach as mentioned in it.

Comment: HEY BANANA, please show me how.

Comment: @Munira you can find a good solution in the thread suggested by harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with pure css with borders. Create a content with `:after` pseudo class with css and then set its height and width to 0. You could change the width of  your triangle by changing `border-width` property. Its easier to show it than saying. Here is a [demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1ot4gf1/) to play around.

**html**

```
<div></div>
```

**css**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    width: 500px;
    background: tomato;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
div:after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 40px 100px 40px 0;
    border-color: transparent tomato transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but it requires very accurate calculation, and might be broken with different resoluion and browser, if I am guessing correct.

Comment: If you are talking about absolute positing wrap your menu with a div and make its positioning relative. so the triangle will stay wherever you want and  safe to use https://jsfiddle.net/f1ot4gf1/1/