# Bordered box with arrow at right center

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to code a border like in the picture.

[image]

```css
p{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some texts</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.speechbubble{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.speechbubble:after{
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-left:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    top:50px;
    right:-6px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="speechbubble"></div>
```

Here's also a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9ve2sw5/)