# Transition icon when hover

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I've this code

```css
.pictos {
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 160px 0 30px;
  padding: 0 17%;
  width: 100%;
}
.pictos > div {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-row;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}
.pictos a.standard:hover,
.pictos a.standard:focus {
  background: url("http://s11.postimg.org/91k4hiqe7/standard.png") no-repeat scroll 50% -39px rgba(120, 182, 55, 1);
}
.pictos > div a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;
  width: 45px;
}
/* Hide this */

.pictos > div .standard-hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;
  width: 45px;
}
.pictos > div:first-child {} .pictos a.standard {
  background: url("http://s11.postimg.org/91k4hiqe7/standard.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.pictos a.standard:hover span,
.pictos a.standard span:hover,
.pictos a.standard span:focus,
.pictos a.standard:focus span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.pictos a span::after {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #78b637 rgba(120, 182, 55, 0) rgba(120, 182, 55, 0);
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
.pictos a span {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #78b637;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 9px;
  bottom: 50px;
  color: #efefef;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 77px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pictos">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="standard">
      <span>standard</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="standard-hover">
      <span>standard</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is when you hover the link, an white icon phone (like this http://s30.postimg.org/3l9qho5h9/standard_hover.png) appears from the bottom to the green circle. It happens when the first icon is moving to the top.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.pictos {
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 160px 0 30px;
  padding: 0 17%;
  width: 100%;
}
.pictos > div {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-row;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}

/* new stuff: */
.pictos a.standard {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  /* set two background images: */
  background-image: url("http://s11.postimg.org/91k4hiqe7/standard.png"), 
                    url(http://s30.postimg.org/3l9qho5h9/standard_hover.png);
  /* set positioning for them both individually: */
  background-position: 50% 50%, 50% 39px;
}
.pictos a.standard:hover,
.pictos a.standard:focus {
  /* when hovering, change background-color and both of the background-positions: */
  background-color: rgba(120, 182, 55, 1);
  background-position: 50% -39px, 50% 50%;
}
/* end of new stuff, removed some other unnecessary rules also*/

.pictos > div a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;
  width: 45px;
  position:relative;
}
.pictos a.standard:hover span,
.pictos a.standard span:hover,
.pictos a.standard span:focus,
.pictos a.standard:focus span {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.pictos a span::after {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #78b637 rgba(120, 182, 55, 0) rgba(120, 182, 55, 0);
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
.pictos a span {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #78b637;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 9px;
  color: #efefef;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-50px;
  left:-77px;
  opacity:0;
  height:16px;
  transition:opacity .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="pictos">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="standard">
      <span>standard</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited it a bit, I put in some explanation in comments, did that clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I have started with a different approach, using pseudo elements to contain your icons, and animated them on hover.

I have also added an `<a>` tag to allow you to have text as well

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.phone {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.phone:before,
.phone:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://s11.postimg.org/91k4hiqe7/standard.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 60%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.wrap:hover .phone:before {
  top: -100%;
}
.phone:after {
  top: 100%;
  background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/3l9qho5h9/standard_hover.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: 60%;
}
.wrap:hover .phone:after {
  top: 0;
}
.wrap:hover .phone {
  background: green;
}
a, span {
  transition: all 0.6s;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
a span {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#"><span>Standard</span>
  <div class="phone"></div>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: @CorentinBranquet: I've just edited to include the arrow as well (based on my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow/30299094#30299094)). If you need any more help on this feel free to comment and i'll see what I can do!

Comment: Is it possible to put the text on top ? not below the icon

Comment: And make the icon clickable as well not only the text

Comment: @CorentinBranquet: Done. Only issue is with that is that I've had to put the hover effect on the `.wrap` div, otherwise I would have to use jQuery/script to display the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-width: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
button:before{
  content:'☎';
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 6px;
  transition: top 1s;
}
button:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
button:hover:before{
  top:-100px;
}
button:after{
  content:'☎';
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 7px;
  transition: top 1s;
}
button:hover:after{
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<button />
```