# How do you make this effect?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

How does one make this little triangle bump at the bottom as on the picture bubble?

What is the best way to do it without using images?

Comment: Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ Has a lot of handy shapes.

Comment: Using the `::after` CSS selector and `position` styling and giving the shape using `border` some of the colors of it being transparent

Comment: Google first https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20chat%20bubble.

Comment: Sure, this is not duplicate question but consice **design pattern** question. The thing has name 'Speech Bubble' and looks precisely as described in the question.

Comment: @IvanBorisenko: There are so many speech bubble questions in SO that have been asked and answered thoroughly already. There was no need for another one and it is rightly closed as duplicate. For example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow?lq=1) is one from the Linked posts section and I am sure you can find many of those.

Comment: @Harry yes, that linked one is great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This thing named 'Speech Bubble'.

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.triangle-isosceles {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 1em 0 3em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0095ff;
}

.triangle-isosceles:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50px;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0095ff transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="triangle-isosceles">Address</p>
```

Check out this example: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: relative;
  top: 36px;
  left: -75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0;
  border-color: lightblue transparent;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sbu2mg87/)

The `::after` CSS pseudo is important, since that is what creates the little cursor at the bottom.

Comment: It is better to include local snippet instead of jsfiddle link.

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but when you vote to close a question as a duplicate, it is better not to post an answer. From the timelines, your duplicate vote should have been cast before you answered.