# triangle border not showing completely and has a hidden head

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

First: i have a slide in (start.html) in **[this page](https://15120f2ac1ff61eee2ed662c243d914d10b9a2cf.googledrive.com/host/0Bzc09sLnqtkMTVNmMWJla2djTlU/tabs)**. To move thumb images row to top I changed border,margin,padding,exchange top and left in slider stylesheet but my triangle border lost its head (start2.html).

minimized page: jsfiddle.net/ht6gmaku/

**I already know how to create triangle border** can anybody tell me the reason for corrupted display.

[the original and changed slide stylesheets page](https://15120f2ac1ff61eee2ed662c243d914d10b9a2cf.googledrive.com/host/0Bzc09sLnqtkMTVNmMWJla2djTlU/tabs/style/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may find help here: [Speech bubble with arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give height 100% at the thumbs container:

```
.ms-tabs-template .ms-thumb-list.ms-dir-h {
  top: -101px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;//GIVE 100%
}
```

Result:

[image]