# Remove triangle(?) ::before on bootstrap 2.3.2 dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a navbar that can be configured to be both vertical or horizontal placed on a page.
It is for a widget on a system using bootstrap 2.3.2.

I want to remove or move the triangle above the dropdown. (What is it called?)

I have tried to set the ::before to display:none , content:none, etc without any success.
Altering the css position left and top only seem to affect the border.
Is there no way to remove/hide this in a neat way? or even better, position it on the left side, towards the navbar?

[image]

```
.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:before {
position: absolute;
top: -7px;
left: 9px;
display: inline-block;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
content: '';
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
```

Or is this default behavior from bootstrap?
The menu is created by reading through a JSON, so i was hoping for to use the same code for the vertical and horizontal menu, since this is just a visual "issue".

Comment: to help you understand how such a triangle is created check out this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921229/box-with-a-triangle-like-a-chat

For your problem: the "left" parameter defines the position and the triangle consists only of borders, so you have to alter or remove the borders to change its appearance or make it disappear

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. the ::before only makes up the borders, while the ::after makes up the white triangle background. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solved by setting content to none on both ::before and ::after.
Should have thought of that ::Before I posted.