# Remove shadow of triangle from overlapping area above content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I wanted to remove inner border or box from the box, as shown below

**below image:**

**Note:** if possible i want to retain my code with bit addition

**Note2:** i don't want to remove `box-shadow` on `element` or `:after`

[image]

here is my codepen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEwgRR

```css
#messagebox,#messagebox2{
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  font-size:18px;
  border-radius:3%;
  box-shadow:0px 8px 9px black;
  margin-top:80px;
}

#messagebox:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:65%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0px 5px 9px black;
}

#messagebox2:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:65%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0px 5px 9px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="messagebox">
   hello world
</div>

<div id="messagebox2">
   hello world
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance  !!!!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow/30299094#30299094

Answer (score 2):

- Create another layer using `::before` pseudo element of same width / height as parent.
- Apply shadow on this layer instead of parent element.
- Add some negative `z-index` value to place it below the `::after` pseudo element i.e arrow.

**Demo:**

```css
.messagebox {
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  font-size:18px;
  margin-top:80px;
}

.messagebox::before {
  box-shadow:0px 8px 9px black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:3%;
  content: '';
  z-index: -2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.messagebox:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:65%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0px 5px 9px black;
}

.messagebox2:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
  bottom:-25px;
  right:65%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0px 5px 9px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagebox">
   hello world
</div>

<div class="messagebox messagebox2">
   hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```css
.messagebox {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.messagebox:after {
  border: 16px solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent red red;
  bottom: -30px;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagebox">Hello World!</div>
```