# Css / Styled Cutting a div as a ballon question

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hello i'm trying to do like an arrow from a question balloon:

code:

```
<Styled.MessageWrapper user={message.user}>
            <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} user={message.user} />
            <Styled.ChatMessage user={message.user}>
              {message.text}
            </Styled.ChatMessage>
          </Styled.MessageWrapper>
```

css:

```
const MessageWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: ${props => (props.user ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start')};
`;
const BotImg = styled.img`
  display: ${props => (props.user ? 'none' : 'block')};
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
`;
const ChatMessage = styled.div`
  margin: 1ex;
  padding: 1ex;
  border-radius: 2px;
  ${props => (props.user ? messageClient : messageBot)}
`;
```

now i have this:

[image]

i trying make this but not sucess:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about styled components. However, this solution with just HTML and CSS might help demonstrate how to leverage the technique already recommended by @BugsArePeopleToo.

```css
.messages {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.message {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.message.tx {
  text-align: right;
}

.message .bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #0D47A1;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.message.rx .bubble {
  background: #CFD8DC;
  color: #212121;
}

.message .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #CFD8DC;
}

.bubble.l-caret::before,
.bubble.r-caret::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-top: 0.5em solid #0D47A1;
}

.message.rx .bubble.l-caret::before,
.message.rx .bubble.r-caret::before {
  border-top: 0.5em solid #CFD8DC;
}

.bubble.l-caret::before {
  left: -0.5em;
}

.bubble.r-caret::before {
  right: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">

  <div class="message rx">
    <span class="icon"> </span>
    <span class="bubble l-caret">
      test 123 hello world <br>
      multiline
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="message tx">
    <span class="bubble r-caret">
      ohai
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a pseudo element on your `ChatMessage` component.

The syntax for styled components is:

```
const ChatMessage = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    /* additional pseudo element styles here */
  }
`;
```

As for the styles of the arrow, you need relative/absolute positioning, and use the transparent border trick to get a triangle. Here is anther question on SO that explains this technique very well, just adjust the positioning, dimensions, color, border, etc to your liking: [Speech bubble with arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow)

Comment: hello i'm trying but i'm getting really bad results
Can you help me? https://prnt.sc/qvrphu

Comment: @gabriel Woodrow Barlow's got the arrow styling working nicely in their answer.