# Speech bubble using CSS

Tags: css

As I'm not expert in CSS, requesting help everyone. am trying to create speech bubble like below. but i could only able to get oval shape. I don't know how add tail on top right corner.

I've gone through all **SO solution but don't know which CSS property need to change** to make top right tail as per below image.

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="flat-oval"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .flat-oval {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  position: relative;
  left: 0%
}

.bubble-wrapper{
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

that tail should be bit long and lean.

Thanks to all

Comment: have a look at lea's pens http://projects.verou.me/bubbly/

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo yeah i've already seen this. i played with that also but still not able to get that Curved like bending

Comment: If you're not bound to have that exact design, you can always follow these directions in how to create tooltips with arrows: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like below:

```css
.speech {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000)
}

.speech:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: -10%;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use clip-path property in case of creating that tail thing. Using clip-path you can create any kind of shape you want. Here is some link that might help to learn more about clip-path.
similar kind of project: https://freefrontend.com/css-speech-bubbles/
clip-path documentary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score -1):

I hope Its useful to you..

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-70%, -50%);
      width: 80vmin;
      height: 80vmin;
  }


  .bubble-wrapper div {
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .b {
      border: 0.5vmin solid black;
  }

  .r {
      border-radius: 100%;
  }

  .hb::before,
  .ha::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
  }

  .bubble {
      width: 40%;
      height: 25%;
      left: 73%;
      top: 10%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 5vmin;
      background: #ffd;
      box-shadow: 0 -0.25vmin, 0 0.125vmin;
      font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Neue", sans-serif;
  }

  .bubble::before {
      width: 40%;
      height: 250px;
      bottom: -10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      left: -60px;
      box-shadow: 0.5vmin 0, 3vmin -1vmin #ffd, 3vmin -1vmin 0 0.5vmin;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 49%, 150% 51%, 150% 100%, 0% 100%);
      transform: rotateZ(-210deg) scaleX(-1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble b r hb">Hello....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not exactly as per attachment. anyhow i tired like `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(40% 47%, 58% 60%, 64% 68%, 73% 79%, 53% 76%, 48% 67%, 31% 52%, 0 33%);
clip-path: polygon(40% 47%, 58% 60%, 64% 68%, 73% 79%, 53% 76%, 48% 67%, 31% 52%, 0 33%);`  . but tail is not coming as expected