# Applying a border to an element with mask-image

Tags: css, svg

Currently I have an tooltip element and I need to apply a border to it. The follow code describes the problem.

```css
.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 28rem;
    padding: 8px 8px 18px 8px;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(180.43deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0.74%, rgb(5, 180, 98) 124.74%);
    -webkit-mask-image:
                radial-gradient(#fff 4.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5px),
                radial-gradient(#fff 4.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5px),
                radial-gradient(#fff 4.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5px),
                radial-gradient(#fff 4.5px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5px),
                linear-gradient(#fff, #fff),
                linear-gradient(#fff, #fff),
                url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='20px' height='10px' viewBox='0 0 60 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M 0 0 L 60 0 L 30 30 Z'/></svg>");
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position:
                0 0,
                100% 0,
                0 calc(100% - 10px),
                100% calc(100% - 10px),
                0 5px,
                5px 0,
                calc(10% - 10px) 100%;
    -webkit-mask-size:
                10px 10px,
                10px 10px,
                10px 10px,
                10px 10px,
                100% calc(100% - 20px),
                calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px),
                20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
    <div>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to apply a border `1px solid red` to this element however this wont work as (obviously) it will be hidden by the mask, anything that draws outside the mask is hidden.

Things I've tried that haven't worked:

- border: 1px solid red;
- `feMorphology` border + filter(#svg_id) - This will only ever draw the border outside (not inset)
- Adding a child div with identical mask, adding border: 1px solid red AND background-color: red; to the root element. **This almost completely works however if you try this you'll notice the triangle at bottom doesn't quite have a perfect border**
- box-shadow
- drop-shadow

Any solution cannot involve separating the triangle + content into separate elements as this will break that gradient. Solutions must leave the gradient background.

### Comment on possible duplicate

I understand there are many similar questions on Stack Overflow (I've searched myself). Please try them on this element; I've tried all the ways I can find. The problems are that SVG only solutions wont work on div, separating the triangle will remove gradient, and adding a child element with 1px gap between him and the parent will not actually get a perfect border around the triangle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65682691/8620333

Comment: There are many differences in that question and others on stack overflow and my use case. My element is not an SVG, You cannot just stack drop-shadows (try it), You cannot add a child div with identical mask and 1px gap between that and the parent because the triangle will be offset 1px and the effect will be missing on the right side of the triangle.

Comment: Sorry and missed the main difference, the accepted answer on that creates a separate element for the triangle, try apply my background: linear-gradient to their solution and you'll see the triangle will break the gradients color.

Comment: the last snippet of my answer contains exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65682691/8620333 .. a triangle at the bottom, a gradient coloration and a border (and a lot of different variation that you can easily control using CSS varibles)

Comment: Thanks man checked this last snippet, It does indeed look like what I want but I can't for the life of me get it working. Applying my background to any of those examples causes issues with the triangle, Tried modifying the css variables h/w to 10px height + 20px width (to match my triangle) respectively.

Any chance you could post example here? OR update the code on your other answer with my example?

Comment: Also I think that relies on hardcoded height/width; Because I can see those being used in the calculations in your background gradient @TemaniAfif

Comment: for you case, stacking the drop-shadow is enough since you already have the shape: https://jsfiddle.net/d7c4ka8o/

Comment: Absolute legend man will upvote original post thank you

Comment: Unfortunately drop-shadow introduces blurring around the shape (for the color I'm using) but found a solution by positioning a SVG icon absolutely and adding stroke to it to get a border around the triangle part, then border around rest is easy.